# unusual dot's at my html code

Tags: html

There's some dots in my html code when I see the code from browser(like `image_1`), but I cant find it on the code. How you can see in the first image, there's a dot before `DOCTYPE`, but, when I go to my `header.php`, there's nothing before`DOCTYPE(image_2)`.

[image: image_1]

[image: image_2]

Comment: Where's the PHP code?

Comment: try to open in a plain text editor and see if there is something there.

Comment: Is there PHP? Your question should include your code, otherwise we are just throwing out guesses here. Your question tagged PHP so I assumed you were using PHP to build this.

Comment: Does it happens in the local file or only in the hosted file?

Comment: Yes, there's php, but the dot appears just in same pages, not at all.  freestock.tk it happens in the local file!

Comment: bansi, the code is normal ate notepad, there's no dot...

Comment: Solved, thanks guys!!!